# Ubuntu 12.10(32bit) takes very long to install - horribly slow it's a compliment

Tags: installation

I'm really new on ubuntu so I have a question, but first of all let me tell everything I know before asking:

A week(or two) ago I bought an Second-Hand PC(just for using it with UBUNTU) and I've successfully installed Ubuntu 12.10 (in a very short time, like 30-90 min, didn't count at all - the main thing it's that the installation process went very well). The next week I played with it(installed printer, scanner, made updates, played some games etc.) untill I "broke" it and didn't find any solution(after a very long research). The last thing I did was to install PHP + cURL for a mini-script, but also on that day in the upper right corner appeared a red triangle or something like that, which said something about not able to install an update(or something like that, I didn't have internet connection at all that day so I just ignored it). After 2-3 hours it froze and I was never been able to boot again(tried nomodeset, apt-get update && apt-get upgrade etc, this doesn't count at all).

The LIVE DISC(from a USB) played well so I decided for a fresh install since I didn't have anything important on it(recovered all files via CLI + ftp).

After I decided to install it again I let the PC run for ~6hours and it didn't finish at all.

Last night(10PM GMT+2) I let it install overnight. It's already 12.00AM and it still has not finished.

Now it's at : ubuntu_supplicant[2282]: Group rekeying completed with MACADDR(it's actually a mac address) - this line appears multiple times from about 9:00AM (along with other lines like "cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron/hourly).

The configuration of PC:
Intel CELERON E3300 2,50GHz x 2
RAM : 1,8GB(i bought knowing it was 2GB)
HDD: 250GB
Graphic Card : don't really know (I didn't care at all - i have better pc & laptop for design & gaming).

Q: It's normally what it happens? More than 14 hours and it didn't install yet? Why I have this problem, since the first time worked very well? The orange bar looks like it's at about 75%.

Thanks & sorry for my bad english :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is downloading files runtime while installing. If same is the case and your internet connection is slow, you may have faced the issue.

Comment: It have a very fast internet connection (10-15MB/s download locally). I tested it with firefox by downloading a big package(100MB - 8-9s). Also yesterday (when i waited ~6hours) I haven't checked the "download and install updates" box and it still didn't went fast. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Which option did you choose to start installing Ubuntu?

Maybe it is trying to recover information frol your last installation.

I suggest you choose the **something else** option while installing. Then delete all partitions and recreate one big partition for the OS (mount point: /) and a small (4Gb for example) Swap partition.

You should end up with a completely fresh installation.

Comment: I tried the "remove and install" or something like that. For now I stopped the installation process and will try to connect in recovery mode with nmcli and do some apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. If i will resolve I'll let you know. Thanks!